# Angular cookies appearing with encoded characters

Tags: javascript, cookies, angularjs, angular-cookies

Given some data:

```
$scope.devices = [
  { name: 'iPhone 4', os: 'iOS'},
  { name: 'Nexus 7', os: 'Android'},
];
```

And a function to set a cookie:

```
$scope.saveDeviceChoice = function() {
  $cookieStore.put('savedDevice', $scope.deviceChoice.name);
}
```

I get a cookie with value %22Nexus%207%22 instead of what I would expect: Nexus 7.

This is what it looks like in the web inspector
[image]

I am truly puzzled - it seems that %22 is a quote and %20 is a space, somehow the value gets saved "encoded". Who knows what is going on?

Answer (score 7):

Here is the official doc for $cookieStore:

> Provides a key-value (string-object) storage, that is backed by session cookies. Objects put or retrieved from this storage are **automatically serialized or deserialized by angular's toJson/fromJson.**

Then the store save the **URL encoded** version of the value. Take a look at [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/), there is a section explaining the cookie encoding.

Comment: this is a pain when reading the cookie from backend you have to decode it back to be able to use it

Answer (score 4):

$cookieStore.(get/put) automatically run to/from Json on the value you send over, which appends the encoded characters.

If you were to just use $cookies then you can get away with setting your parameters as such

```
$cookies['savedDevice'] = $scope.deviceChoice.name;
```

or

```
$cookies.savedDevice = $scope.deviceChoice.name;
```

Either way, the values are saved just like you want em to be.

Usage of $cookieStore is popular, however comes with it's own baggage if you want to use the values on the server.